# After US Supreme Court overturns precedent, are old cases revisited?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court, precedent, hypothetical

Hypothetical scenario:

- 1950: government uses method A to convict John Doe of crime B, SCOTUS upholds conviction
- 1990: government uses method A to convict Jake Smith of crime B
- 2000: government uses method A to convict Jane Roe of crime B, SCOTUS overturns decision from 1950, vacates Roe's conviction

What would now happen to Smith's conviction, if anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard is [this](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2015/10/what-happens-to-old-sentences-when-the-law-changes/410455/), from [Teague v. Lane](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/489/288/case.html):

> If a case announces a “new rule,” an opinion by Justice Sandra Day
>   O’Connor said, the new rule will apply to all cases pending on direct
>   review; but in most cases it will not apply to cases already final.

There are two exceptions:

> First, a “new rule” will apply retroactively if it is “substantive,”
>   meaning eliminating certain crimes (all sodomy cases, say, after
>   Lawrence v. Texas) or protecting certain classes of people from
>   certain punishments—as in the Court’s recent decisions that juvenile
>   offenders and the intellectually disabled cannot be sentenced to
>   death. The issue in Montgomery is whether the new rule against “true
>   life” sentences for juvenile is that kind of “substantive” rule. The
>   Miller Court said that states could no longer subject juvenile
>   defendants to automatic sentences of life without parole; it didn’t
>   say that a court could not sentence any juveniles to that penalty. Is
>   that a “substantive” exclusion of juveniles—or a requirement of
>   individualized sentencing that makes a mere “procedural” change to the
>   law?
>
> The second exception to Teague is for a “watershed rule of criminal
>   procedure,” meaning one that the Court finds to be an “absolute
>   prerequisite” to a fair and accurate trial. This is a terrific
>   exception except that, well, there seemingly aren’t any “watershed
>   cases.”

Comment: I don't suppose you have a citation for this?

Comment: Changed the answer. Sorry. Had answered it with what I think should be true rather than how it currently is.

Comment: Heh, good.  I was just about to write my own answer citing Teague; now I don't have to.

Comment: In a previous job, we advocated in a state legislature so relentlessly for retroactivity to be applied to the state law changes that were required in the aftermath of the juvenile without parole issue that I forgot we, sadly, had not prevailed in that fight!

Comment: Thanks for commenting and making me double check, by the way!

Comment: The technical term that you'll usually see regarding this doctrine is [*res judicata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Res_judicata), which applies to cases unless there are significant changes to the law (not the facts!)